# non-unicode WM_CHAR in unicode windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, unicode

I have written a DLL which exports a function that creates a window using `RegisterClassExW` and `CreateWindowExW`. Every message is retrieved via

```
GetMessageW(&msg, wnd_handle, 0, 0);
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessageW(&msg);
```

Also there is a program which loads the DLL and calls the function.

Despite the Unicode window creation method, the `wParam` in the `WM_CHAR` message always contains ASCII characters, even if I type some non-ASCII symbols or use Alt+(code). Instead of UTF-16, the `wParam` contains some ASCII character between 'A' and 'z'.
The `WndProc` is a static function inside the DLL.

The problem doesn't occur when all the window-related code is inside one program.

Is there a way to always have Unicode `WM_CHAR` messages inside the DLL's window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was in the message retrieval process. I used `GetMessage()` with the handle of my window instead of just 0, `GetMessageW(&msg, wnd_handle, 0, 0)` instead of `GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0)`. 
 In this way, the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` messages were swallowed and the locale remained English.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems like it should work.

Is it possible that you're calling the ANSI DefWindowProc instead of the wide version?  That would translate a `WM_UNICHAR` into ANSI `WM_CHAR` messages.  Maybe that would explain what you're seeing.

As an experiment, I'd handle the `WM_UNICHAR` messages directly, and see what the data looks like at that point.

Comment: I was having trouble handling WM_UNICHAR, and after a bit of searching I found: "To summarize: this is a documentation error. WM_UNICHAR is not generated by Windows. As you inferred, it was intended for use by 3rd party applications. The paragraph about it being posted by TranslateMessage has never been true in any version of Windows." - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d455e846-d18b-4086-98de-822658bcebf0/wmunichar?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but it might help:

Take a look to the settings of the project where you implement the code that calls the DLL functions. Make sure that the character set is UNICODE as well, and not multibyte:

(go to Project Properties, then to General section, and put Character Set option to "Use Unicode Character Set"). I was assuming that you're using Visual Studio 2003 or later.

Comment: The settings are set to Unicode. The _UNICODE preprocessor directive is also set.